# invoking private scope

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a book a little above my level. The book's author is showing how to create private scope with an anonymous function.  I understand the concept of private scope, however, I don't understand how it's achieved.  I do get that these local variables can only be accessed in the current scope (those are the author's words), but I'm not sure how it would be invoked/implemented. Can you give me an example as to how it would be used in actual code using the `var Tim = new Person();` below

Using anonymous function to create private scope:

```
var Person = function(){};

(function(){
  var findById = function(){ /* ... */ };
  Person.find = function(id){
    if (typeof id == "integer")
      return findById(id);
   };
})();
```

My understanding

```
var Tim = new Person();
```

What would I call?  Would I try to find the id of Tim?

Comment: Actually, I tried some code similar to yours and it didn't work. I fixed it by changing 'Person.find' to 'Person.prototype.find'. Using an anonymous function like this is an excellent way to have private class members, or at least something that provides everything that private class members provide. I'm surprised Crockford doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would call `findById` only indirectly by calling `Person.find`:

```
// Assuming code similar to your code above
// Assume that Tim.id === 1
var someone = Person.find(1); // Call findById to get a reference to Tim
console.log(someone.name); // Tim
findById(1) // Error, findById is not available in the global scope
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all: the snippet you've provided will not return the id, but will return something when passed an id. I must admit that this example is not the best of examples when it comes to private scopes. I'll give you a more elaborate, but I hope clearer example:

```
(function ()
{
    var personObjects = [];
    var findById = function(id)
    {
        return personObjects[id];
    }
    var Person = function (name)
    {
        this.id = personObjects.length;//first available index ~= auto increment
        this.name = name;
        personObjects.push(this);
    };
    Person.find = function(id)
    {
        //I woudl do: id = +id;, but sticking to your example
        if (typeof id === 'number')
        {
            return findById(id);
        }
        return undefined;
    }
    window.Person = Person;//expose to global object
})();
```

So, what do we have here. You say you understand about scopes, so I assume you're aware that all variables declared here will *survive* after the wrapper function returns, but that they are only visible to the functions that were declared in the same scope. If not: the `personObjects` array and `findById` function object will exists, still, but can only be accessed by the `Person` constructor, which is exposed (because assigned too) the global object.

I'm using the array's length to determine the next available ID whenever a person object is instantiated, thus creating a unique id for every Object. The function findById simply returns a reference to one of the objects when you pass a valid id (array key) to it. The `Person.find` method calls this enclosed function, but does some checks on the arguments before doing so. This could, in some very specific cases be useful for debugging, or use of generic setters and getters in a long prototype chain. That's why, to me at least, this example is a little far fetched as a starting point.

Anyhow, you call this private method (`findById`) like so:

```
var tim = new Person('tim');
Person.find(0);// returns a reference to tim
//or even
var tom = new Person('Tom');
tim.find(1);//returns tom
tom.find(0);//returns tim
tim.find(tom.id);//...
```

Again, this approach isn't too common AFAIK, to practice/get used to scopes and closures I'd suggest working some magic with `setInterval` and event delegation (for example: try to create your own delegator for a `tab` event on mobile devices). Just google them, you'll soon see why it's a good exercise, but a bit daunting at first.